# iTunes is sometimes "Connecting to Store" again and again

Tags: itunes

iTunes is showing this "Connecting to Store" alert. I know this is caused by the cover-search when I add new songs. But sometimes it happens when starting the app, it stucks and says "Connecting to Store" again and again. Most of the time I have to close the App.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can we assume that you have an active Internet connection when running iTunes?  Try unchecking "Automatically download missing album artwork" in iTunes preferences and let us know if that helps.

Comment: I unchecked the option and now it has stopped. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you happen to have a proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **iTunes** → **Preferences** → **Store**.
2. Uncheck **Automatically download album artwork**.

[image: iTunes Store Preferences → Automatically download album artwork]

Comment: @grgarside thnx for the edit, makes it look so much nicer ^_^